# How to design a table of worker roles

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design

I need help with database designing.

So far I have three tables:

```
TblDepartments
--------------
DeptID (PK)
DeptName

TblSections
-----------
SectionID (PK)
DeptID (FK)
SectionName

TblWorkers
----------
WorkerID (PK)
WorkerName
```

There is a 1:N relationship between Departments and Sections (a department may have several sections, a section belongs to one department).

Now, a worker may have a role either at the section level or at the department level (i.e. have the same role in all sections of the department).

I'm not sure how I should define the Roles table. I came with this definition:

```
TblRoles
--------
WorkerID  (PK)(FK)
DeptID    (PK)(FK)
SectionID (PK)(FK)
RoleDesc
```

But I don't like this solution and I feel it's wrong. (Either DeptID or SectionID must be null, and SectionID is dependent on DeptID anyway).

Is there a better way to define the Roles table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll need a table of just roles since you can't have repeating data.

```
roles
-----
roleId
name
```

Can a worker have more than one role?

```
workerRole
----------
workerId
roleId
```

If a worker will only have a single role, just add it to your worker table

```
worker
------
workerId
name
roleId
```

If a role can belong to a section and department, then one table for each:

```
departmentRole        sectionRole
--------------        -----------
departmentId          sectionId
roleId                roleId
```

[*Don't prefix your tables with `tbl`*](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/don-t-prefix-your-table-names-with-tbl)

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of Sections and Departments is nearly identical, you could use a self-join

```
Create Table Departments 
    ( 
    DeptId ... not null Primary Key
    , ParentDeptId null References Departments ( DeptId )
    , Name ... not null Unique
    )
```

In this structure, a Department with a null ParentDeptId is a Department and one with a non-null ParentDeptId is a section. Then your roles table is straight forward:

```
Create Table Roles
    (
    WorkerId ... not null References Workers ( WorkerId )
    , DeptId ... not null References Departments ( DeptId )
    , Description ... not null
    )
```

Another choice is to create a table that captures company's hierarchy.

```
Create Table Departments 
    ( 
    DeptId ... not null Primary Key
    , Name ... not null Unique
    )

Create Table Sections
    (
    SectionId ... not null Primary Key
    , Name ... not null Unique
    )
```

In the following table, where SectionId is null, it represents a department and where SectionId is not null it obviously represents a Section.

```
Create Table CompanyAreas
    (
    Id ... not null Primary Key
    , DeptId ... not null References Departments ( DeptId )
    , SectionId ... null References Sections ( SectionId )
    , Unique ( DeptId, SectionId )
    )

Create Table WorkerRoles
    (
    CompanyAreaId ... not null References CompanyAreas ( Id )
    , WorkerId ... not null References Workers ( WorkerId )
    , Description ... not null
    )
```